# echo data sent from controller in view

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am not able to echo the data that is returned from the controller in my view. The controller is returning proper data. i.e print_r($data['notice_period']);
            die; returns the array below

```html
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [userid] => 1 [emp_code] => 047 [emp_shift] => 2nd Shift [emp_category] => Full Time [cccode] => [prefix] => Dr. [firstname] => admin [middlename] => [lastname] => unfold [designation_id] => 8 [division_id] => [branch_id] => 4 [company] => [email] => admin@unfold.com [personal_email] => [nickname] => [url] => [birthday] => 18-03-1980 [panno] => [passportno] => [passportdate] => [joining_date] => 14-07-2016 [resignation_date] => 01-01-1970 [team_id] => [tag_ids] => [im] => [facebook] => [twitter_handle] => [linkedin_id] => [instagram] => [googleplus] => [maidenname] => [profileimage] => 1458813725_421139936.jpg [blood_group] => A Positive [gender] => Male [married] => [anniversary] => 24-06-2009 [ctc] => [mood] => Happy toda [doc_type] => [org_to] => [org_from] => [org] => [role_title] => [org_skills] => [scanned_doc_work] => [pass_year] => [adm_year] => [degree] => [univ] => [edu_scanned_doc] => [declare_home] => 1 [declare_menu1] => 1 [declare_family] => 1 [declare_menu4] => 1 [declare_menu7] => 1 [declare_menu8] => 1 [declare_menu2] => [declare_menu3] => [s_cluster_id] => 2 [status] => 1 [deleted] => 0 [registrationtime] => 0 [timemodified] => 0 [modifierid] => 0 [alternate_email] => [notice_period] => 10 ) )
```

I am trying to print the notice period in a readonly textbox but failed. Here is my view code:

```html
  <?php echo form_input(array("name" =>"notice_period" ,"id"=>"notice_period","class"=>"m-wrap form-control ","value"=>$data->notice_period))?>
```

My controller code is:

```html
   $data['notice_period']=$this->exit_common->get_notice_period($USER);
   $this->data['maincontent'] = $this->load->view('maincontents/exit_add_view', $data,true); 
   $this->load->view('layout', $this->data);
```

How to print the notice period in my view? Its showing blank

edit_add_view.php

```html
<!-- Main content -->
<!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->

<!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
<style>
tr > td
{
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}
</style>
<section class="content-header">
<h1>
Add Resignation Request

</h1>
<ol class="breadcrumb">
<li><a href="<?php base_url(); ?>"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">My Requests</a></li>
<li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>exits/resignation_request">Resignation Requests</a></li>
<li class="active">Add Resignation Request</li>
</ol>
</section>
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<!-- Thought Day-->
<div class="panel wrapper clearfix m-b-none">

<div class="panel-body">

<input type="hidden" id="page_name" value="requests">

<?php if($error_message!=''){?>
<div class="success-message <?php echo $msg_class;?>"><?php echo $error_message;?>  </div>
<?php }  else { ?>
<?php  $row = $rows[0] ;
if(isset($row['grievance_type'])) {
$grievancetype = $row['grievance_type'];
} else { $grievancetype = ''; }

?>

<!-- form start -->
<?php echo form_open('exits/my_resignation_request/'.$id,array('name'=>'addostcstevent','id'=>'addostcstevent','method'=>'post','autocomplete'=>'on','class'=>'form-horizontal'))?>
<?php echo form_hidden(array('id'=>$row->id,'action'=>$action));?>
<div class="box-body">

<input type="hidden" name="todays_date" readonly id="todays_date" value="<?php echo date('m/d/y');?>" class="form-control col-md-10" <?php if($USER->permissions[0] != 'all') { ?> readonly <?php } ?>>


  <table class="table table-striped" style="margin-top:40px">
    <td>


   

  <?php echo form_input(array("name" =>"notice_period" ,"id"=>"notice_period","class"=>"m-wrap form-control ","value"=>$data->notice_period))?>
    </td>

        <thead>
      <tr>
        <th><input placeholder="Date of Request" id="dateofrequest" type="button" name="todays_date" value="Date of request: <?php echo date('m/d/y');?>" readonly/></th>
        <th><input placeholder="Status" id="status" type="button" name="status" value="Status: Processing" readonly/></th>
      
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><label>Reason</label></td>
        <td>

      <select name="reason" class="form-control">
            <?php 

            foreach($reasons as $row)
            { 
              echo '<option value="'.$row->reasons.'">'.$row->reasons.'</option>';
            }
            ?>
            </select>
  
  
  </td>
       
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><label>Requested Last Working Day</label></td>
        <td><div class="date" data-date="12-02-2012" data-date-format="mm-dd-yyyy" data-date-viewmode="years">
<input placeholder="Requested Last working day" class="col-md-4 form-control " id="startdt" type="text" name="requested_date" value="" required/></td>
        
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><label>Comments</label></td>
        <td><textarea required class="form-control" name="comments"></textarea></td>
      
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>



</div><!-- /.box-body -->
<div class="box-footer">
<?php

echo form_hidden('action',$action);
echo form_hidden('id',$id);
?>
<!--<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info pull-right" name="withdraw" style="margin:0px 10px" value="withdrawn">Withdraw Resignation</button>-->

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info pull-right" style="margin:0px 10px">Submit</button>





</div><!-- /.box-footer -->
</form>
<?php } ?>
</div><!-- /.box -->
</div><!--/.col (right) -->
</div>   <!-- /.row -->
<div class="modal fade" role="dialog" id="myLTAModal">

<div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
<h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Alert!</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<!-- modal content-->
<div class="panel-body">
<p>Ensure you refer to LTA guidelines before planning your trip. You will be required to submit your tickets as proof to avail LTA.</p>
</div>
</div>
<!-- modal content-->
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="modal fade" role="dialog" id="leaveAllowedModal">

<div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
<h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Alert!</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<!-- modal content-->
<div class="panel-body">
<p class="allowed_text"></p>
</div>
</div>
<!-- modal content-->
</div>
</div>
</div>
</section><!-- /.content -->



<script>
/*$(document).ready(function(){
$('#reservation').daterangepicker();
})*/
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/plugins/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>


<script>
function parseDate(str) {
var mdy = str.split('/')
return new Date(mdy[2], mdy[0]-1, mdy[1]);
}

function daydiff(first, second) {
return Math.round((second-first)/(1000*60*60*24));
}
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#startdt").datepicker({
dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
changeMonth: true,
changeYear: true,
showButtonPanel: true,
yearRange: "-90:+0",
startDate: new Date(),
autoclose: true
}).on('changeDate', function (selected) {
var minDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
$('#enddt').datepicker('setStartDate', minDate);
});
$("#enddt").datepicker({
dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
changeMonth: true,
changeYear: true,
showButtonPanel: true,
yearRange: "-90:+0"
});
$("#enddt").change(function(){
if($("#startdt").val()!='' && $("#enddt").val()!='')
{
var startdt = $("#startdt").val();
var enddt = $("#enddt").val();
$("#daysleave").val(daydiff(parseDate(startdt), parseDate(enddt)));
if($("#grievance_type").val()!='0')
{

var day_diff_today = daydiff(parseDate($("#today_dt").val()), parseDate($("#startdt").val()));

if(((parseInt($("#daysleave").val()) > parseInt($("#grievance_type option:selected").attr("data-min"))) &&  (parseInt($("#daysleave").val()) < parseInt($("#grievance_type option:selected").attr("data-max"))))&&(day_diff_today > parseInt($("#grievance_type option:selected").attr("data-approvaldays"))))
{ } else {
$("#leaveAllowedModal").modal("show");
}

}
}
})
$("#grievance_type").change(function(){
if($("#startdt").val()!='' && $("#enddt").val()!='' && $("#grievance_type").val()!='0')
{
var day_diff_today = daydiff(parseDate($("#today_dt").val()), parseDate($("#startdt").val()));

if(((parseInt($("#daysleave").val()) > parseInt($("#grievance_type option:selected").attr("data-min"))) &&  (parseInt($("#daysleave").val()) < parseInt($("#grievance_type option:selected").attr("data-max"))))&&(day_diff_today > parseInt($("#grievance_type option:selected").attr("data-approvaldays"))))
{ } else {
$("#leaveAllowedModal").modal("show");
}
}
})
$(".date-picker").datepicker();
$("#optionsRadios1").click(function(){
$("#myLTAModal").modal("show");
})
$('#leaveAllowedModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
var msg = '';
if((parseInt($("#daysleave").val()) > parseInt($("#grievance_type option:selected").attr("data-min"))) &&  (parseInt($("#daysleave").val()) < parseInt($("#grievance_type option:selected").attr("data-max"))))
{ } else {
msg = msg + "You wish you apply "+$("#daysleave").val()+" day of "+$("#grievance_type option:selected").text()+". Minimum and Maximum no. of Leaves allowed to take at a time are "+$("#grievance_type option:selected").attr("data-min")+" and "+$("#grievance_type option:selected").attr("data-max")+" respectively.";
}
var day_diff_today = daydiff(parseDate($("#today_dt").val()), parseDate($("#startdt").val()));
if((day_diff_today < parseInt($("#grievance_type option:selected").attr("data-approvaldays"))))
{
msg = msg + " No. of days of prior approval needed is  " + $("#grievance_type option:selected").attr("data-approvaldays") + " days";
}
$(".allowed_text").html(msg);

})
});


</script>
```

Comment: Please provide the view so that we can see where you are going wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass an array to the view. CodeIgniter automatically makes array keys as variable available to you. That means you can access the value with just `$notice_period` not `$data->notice_period`.

Comment: That is because you have a two dimensional array. Check your data array. That contain a array at index of 0. Try sending $data[0] from your controller.

Comment: I have no idea how to do it

Comment: `$this->data['maincontent'] = $this->load->view('maincontents/exit_add_view', $data['notice_period'][0],true);` in you controller.